# JQuery get next to last item from data() array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array stored in `data()`

```
$('body').data('my-array', [red, blue, orange, green]);
```

What is the quickest way to get the penultimate item from the array? In this case `orange`.

I tried:

```
$('body').data('my-array').get(-2);
```

and get `$(...).data(...).get` is not a function.

Note: I found similar questions but not related to arrays from `data()`. Please check before marking as duplicate.

Comment: I did check, and this is still a duplicate.  `$(...).data(...)` returns an array and the solutions given apply to it.  `[1,2,3].get` is also not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('body').data('my-array').reverse()[1]
```

or

```
$('body').data('my-array').slice(-2)[0]
```

or

```
var arr=$('body').data('my-array');
arr.pop();
var item=arr.pop();
```

or

```
var arr=$('body').data('my-array');
var item=arr[arr.length-2];
```

Comment: Hmm the reverse is very clever!

Comment: the reverse is very expensive too !

Comment: @Anonymous0day True.  Updated with more approaches.

Answer (score 5):

Access it like a regular array, which is what it is, and use the length and subtract from it to get the second to last value

```
var arr  = $('body').data('my-array');

var item = arr[arr.length - 2];
```

jQuery's `data()` stores objects and arrays as what they are, there's no magic, and when getting the data back it's accessible like any other object or array.

Note that length starts at 1, and arrays are zero-indexed, so you have to subtract 2.

Comment: Thank you I was thinking that but wondering if there is a more direct way.

Answer (score 2):

You can use javascript's native [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) since its an array (which internally does Array.slice). Something like this

```
$('body').data('my-array').slice(2, -1)[0];
```

`slice(2, -1)` will get the 2 element from the end in an array.

Answer (score -1):

What I would do is use the array length minus 2:

```
array[array.length - 2]
```

Comment: That will give you the last item, not the second to last.